# How to recreate PDF bookmarks after I modify the source file ?

Tags: pdf

I chose Apple Pages to create a PDF manual with bookmarks (TOC in the sidebar for navigation). But as it cannot create those bookmarks, I must create them in another app such as Acrobat. The problem is that I can't import the PDF back in Pages to do modifications while keeping the bookmarks and even if I could, as soon as I would add or remove a page, all bookmarks for the following pages would be wrong.

So is there a tool that could for example generate those bookmarks from a list of text lines and page numbers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X/Apple support for PDF has never been great, and it's only gone downhill as Apple has morphed into a consumer-mobile-electronics company (to the chagrin of the many designers who've relied on that platform for years), so the majority of useful tools are Windows-only.

I did find one Open Source program that looks like it'll do what you need. It's multi-platform, and it's free. Download [here](http://www.freewaregenius.com/2010/05/24/how-to-add-bookmarks-to-a-pdf-document-using-free-software/).

Comment: I finally had time to test jPDFBookmarks, it seems to do the job: it can export and import BM, edit them in all possible way and even offset BM which is exactly what I would need if I added pages. It seems a better tool than Acrobat and easier than the expensive ARTS Aerialist. So thanks.

Comment: Glad to help. That's what we're all here for. :-)